# Getting Error on installing Maven in Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0)

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am trying to install Maven on Eclipse  version Luna Release (4.4.0) and ending up with error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.11.0.20190220-2119 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.11.0.20190220-2119)
  Missing requirement: org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject.ui 1.11.0.20190220-2119 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.11.0.20190220-2119 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.11.0.20190220-2119)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject.ui [1.11.0.20190220-2119]
```

I tried with Maven location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Also tried from MarketSpace

May be my question is very basic but its spoiling my days. :(

Request your help on this.. :)

Thanks

Comment: Well Eclipse Luna is 5 years and 7 releases out of date. The current Maven plug-in may not work with it.

Comment: I strongly recommend to us most recent versions to develop....cause you already have issues with dependencies...

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. i had issue with downloading the latest version of Eclipse so do I tried with this version. Received Eclipse neon version now and let  me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine in Eclipse Neon Version